# WooCommerce Membership calculates taxes of all products twice (Only with an active membership)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, membership, woocommerce-memberships

I have a problem with the calculation of the product tax after binding a membership to a user.

**The product price (in the frontend) without a membership:**
1000$ + 19% tax = 1190$

**The product price (in the frontend) with a membership:**
1190$ + 19% tax = 1416$

It looks like the price receives the tax twice. 
This problem happens only in the **frontend**. In the backend, everything looks fine.

I am using the following Plugins:

- WooCommerce  – 2.6.6
- WooCommerce Subscriptions – 2.0.20
- WooCommerce Memberships – 1.7.2

Also, there are no custom functions that are causing this plugin.

Does anyone have the same issue and maybe a solution for that? 
If you need some more information, please let me know.

Cheers
Jannis

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The membership plugin causes this on the current version.